# UILabel does not change

Tags: iphone, uilabel

my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
NSString *text = @"fjkldsjfkladsjfkljsdaklfjadsklfjdskjfdskjflkdsahfahfdkdfdsfasdfasdfafjkldsjfkladsjfkljsdaklfjadsklfjdskjfdskjflkdsahfahfdkdfdsfasdfasdfass"
                "fjkldsjfkladsjfkljsdaklfjadsklfjdskjfdskjflkdsahfahfdkdfdsfasdfasdfas"
                "fjkldsjfkladsjfkljsdaklfjadsklfjdskjfdskjflkdsahfahfdkdfdsfasdfasdfas";

myLabel = [self getTheHeight:text NameofFont:FONT_NAME fontSize:FONT_SIZE LineMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (UILabel *)getTheHeight:(NSString *)text NameofFont:(NSString *)font_name fontSize:(float)font_size LineMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{
 CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE]];

UILabel *temp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, size.height)];
[temp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE]];
[temp setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[temp setNumberOfLines:0];
temp.text = text;

return temp;
}
```

I have a method that returns the formatted label. the myLabel is putted through IB . The problem is that  the return label does not affect to myLabel.

Whats wrong in code? myLabel does not change text , frame etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Pass your **mylabel** to function like...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
NSString *text = @"fjkldsjfkladsjfkljsdaklfjadsklfjdskjfdskjflkdsahfahfdkdfdsfasdfasdfafjkldsjfkladsjfkljsdaklfjadsklfjdskjfdskjflkdsahfahfdkdfdsfasdfasdfass"
                "fjkldsjfkladsjfkljsdaklfjadsklfjdskjfdskjflkdsahfahfdkdfdsfasdfasdfas"
                "fjkldsjfkladsjfkljsdaklfjadsklfjdskjfdskjflkdsahfahfdkdfdsfasdfasdfas";

[self getTheHeight:text NameofFont:FONT_NAME fontSize:FONT_SIZE LineMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap withLabel:myLabel];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)getTheHeight:(NSString *)text NameofFont:(NSString *)font_name fontSize:(float)font_size LineMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode  withLabel:(UILabel*)temp
{
 CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE]];

temp.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, size.height);
[temp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE]];
[temp setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[temp setNumberOfLines:1];
temp.text = text;
}
```

Comment: it gives error : error: 'temp' redeclared as different kind of symbol

Comment: try to change the value of size.height to any value and setNumberOfLines.

Answer (score 0):

You are not modifying the properties of **myLabel**. Thats the problem here.

A solution for this problem is, Pass the **mylabel** as a parameter to the function and modify the properties with that reference and let the function returns nothing.

Comment: ok but what if i want to return UILabel ? why it does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic problem is to set the proper height of label according to the text.
Try this code:-

It is simpler and you need not to write some extra methods

```
    CGSize labelsize;
    UILabel *commentsTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];;
    [commentsTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [commentsTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    NSString *text = @"fjkldsjfkladsjfkljsdaklfjadsklfjdskjfdskjflkdsahfahfdkdfdsfasdfasdfafjkldsjfkladsjfkljsdaklfjadsklfjdskjfdskjflkdsahfahfdkdfdsfasdfasdfassfjkldsjfkladsjfkljsdakljadsklfjdskjfdskjflkdsahfahf dkdfdsfasdfasdfasfjkldsjfkladsjfkljsdakladsklfjdskjfdskjflkdsahfahfdkdfdsfasdfasdfas";

    [commentsTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"size:14]];
    labelsize=[text sizeWithFont:commentsTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(268, 2000.0) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    commentsTextLabel.frame=CGRectMake(10, 24, 268, labelsize.height);
    [commentsTextLabel release];
```

set your own constraintTosize and frame x and y cordinate.

Comment: thanks for reply... if i write [self.view addSubview temp]; into the custom method than it shows label as expected ... but returning it does not make effect... and I have to write a method for that as I am having many labels...

Comment: you need not writing that I have put this code in my tableviewcellforrow method that why i added.